# How to use UQ in the RHS of assignment operator involving base R functions when using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, quoting

I would like to use variables with varying names (i.e. names defined by using arguments of the function) in the calculations on RHS of assignment operators. Base R functions (`min`, `max`, etc.) interpret the result of the unquoting operand `!!` as string, which is not what I want. How should I specify that R should work with variables names, not strings. No problem when using `!!` with dplyr verbs, such as `select`, `mutate`, etc.

```
df <- tibble(
  g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  g2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  a = sample(5),
  b = sample(5)
)

my_s_mutate <- function(df, group_var, expr) {

  group_var <- enquo(group_var)
  expr <- enquo(expr)
  mean_name <- paste0("mean_", quo_name(expr))
  sum_name <- paste0("sum_", quo_name(expr))

  df %>%
    group_by(!! group_var) %>%
    mutate(
         !! mean_name := mean(!! expr),
         !! sum_name := sum(!! expr),
         diff = !! sum_name - !! mean_name
  )
}

my_s_mutate(df, g1, a)
```

This code give error because is evaluating the difference between two strings. Similar problem occurs when using `min` or `max`

```
 Error in "sum_a" - "mean_a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem!!!

Comment: Have you tried using rlang's double curly (`{{expr}}`)? However, you shouldn't be creating variable col names. If you gave us a larger example and the expected output, we could help you make something better suited to R's vectorization that will avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: I need to create variable col names.The call to the function could be either `my_s_mutate(df, g1, a)` or `my_s_mutate(df, g1, b)`, etc. and result should be able to show if the aggregated statistics are relevant to a or b. This is a very simple example just to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: But you don't...It would be far better to make a "tidy" (long instead of wide) version of the table with one column as "statistic" with mean_X or sum_X and one column with "value" and the value of your statistic. That's what R/the tidyverse was designed to handle best. If you *need* it in long form later (i.e. to do functions on two columns at a time or something), then I would pivot_wider as needed, but as a rule you should keep data tidy or you'll run into strange errors and a lot more work than is actually necessary. If you provide the output you're looking for, it would help me illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function -

```
my_s_mutate <- function(df, group_var, expr) {
  expr1 <- enquo(expr)
  mean_name <- paste0("mean_", quo_name(expr1))
  sum_name <- paste0("sum_", quo_name(expr1))
  
  df %>%
    group_by({{group_var}}) %>%
    mutate(
      !! mean_name := mean({{expr}}),
      !! sum_name := sum({{expr}}),
      diff = .data[[sum_name]] - .data[[mean_name]]
    )
}
```

To work with variable names use `{{}}`, use strings as new column names with `!!` and `:=`. Refer to column names as string with `.data`.

```
my_s_mutate(df, g1, a)

# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   g1 [2]
#     g1    g2     a     b mean_a sum_a  diff
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1     2      3     6     3
#2     1     2     5     3      3     6     3
#3     2     1     2     4      3     9     6
#4     2     2     4     5      3     9     6
#5     2     1     3     1      3     9     6
```